# Construction of Sentence by non-native speaker

Tags: sentence-construction

The main aim to use a certain language is to communicate with each other. 
I'd like to know if the sentence is grammatically and naturally correct.

Comment: I think this question is "proofreading", but I don't understand what the OP is trying to say anyway. More specifically, I can't see any possible meaning for which it makes sense to specifically reference *a **certain** language* when apparently talking about the reason for using [***any***] language.

Comment: I'd be prepared to bet any money that whoever devised the exam questions isn't a native speaker of English. So it's a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is somewhat incorrect. I would rewrite it instead as:

> The main aim of using a certain language is (communication/to communicate) with each other.

Difference of emphasis can be achieved by the variation:

> Communicating with each other is the main aim of using a certain language.

But in this case using "to communnicate" (infinitive) instead of "communicating" (gerund) is uncommon (and arguably incorrect).

Starting with "it is" is somewhat less natural, but possible:

> It is *communicating with each other* that is the main aim of using a certain language.